# What is the difference between UCHAR and WCHAR in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, types

can any body tell me, what is actually the difference between UCHAR and WCHAR.  I am using VC++ 6.0.

Answer (score 4):

UCHAR as rein stated.

WCHAR is NOT a unicode character. This is a common misunderstanding. It's a 16 bit unsigned character, period. However, it **might** be interpreted as a unicode character and it might not be. UTF16 is a multi byte encoding just like UTF8, and might require representation by several WCHAR characters.

Answer (score 2):

A UCHAR is simply an unsigned char (8 bit)

A WCHAR is a unicode character (16 bit)

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505945.aspx) for more info